# wxPython: PyDeadObjectError

Tags: python, wxpython

Running into an error that I've never heard of. I have a task manager that you can minimize to the system tray and when you left click the icon it will reopen but when I do this i get an Pydeadobjecterror. I think it has something to do with the fact that I had two inheritances for one wxpyton class. I then deleted that inheritance and now I'm having errors. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\TrayIcon.py", line 25, in LeftClick
       self.frame.Show()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_core.py", line 14619, in __getattr__
   raise PyDeadObjectError(self.attrStr % self._name)
wx._core.PyDeadObjectError: The C++ part of the MainFrame object has been deleted, attribute access no longer    allowed.
```

so any way I haven't had time to split my code up to multiple files so the code is about 400 lines long so I just pasted it on something easier than pasting it here sorry about that but heres the link  http://bpaste.net/show/liDNQVppFldurLcCfvK8/ and apparently this is the code where the error is http://bpaste.net/show/etcWMPqFC8H6NQRG7uYV/

if some one could help me that would be great

Comment: too much code... but basically self.frame has been destroyed prior to trying to show it ...

Comment: where i dont destroy it anywhere unless you left click the icon?

Comment: presumably some point prior to C:\Python27\TrayIcon.py line 25 in LeftClick... Im guessing when you "minimize" the frame you are destroying it ... but you dont even have a leftclick function in the code you posted ... which is where you are getting the error ...

Comment: i posted the wrong code then i have another code where it minimizes to the system try give me a second ill post that coe

Comment: @JoranBeasley i updated with the code of trayicon but all it is is showing it not destroy it

Comment: maybe this helps im closing it with the x not minimising because it used to just minimize on close

Comment: im pretty sure closing it with x will destroy the frame... you will need to write code to re-initialize your frame I think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are closing the frame with the X, then you are destroying the frame. You need to Hide it instead. I wrote a couple of tutorials about this that you might want to take a look at:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/12/wxpython-how-to-minimize-to-system-tray/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/12/13/wxpython-101-creating-taskbar-icons/

The basic idea is to catch EVT_CLOSE and Hide the frame instead of closing it. You only close the app by right-clicking the system tray icon. You also want to catch EVT_ICONIZE so that when you minimize the frame, you can hide the frame.

Comment: Mike's Blog is literally one of the best python sources on the nets. especially for wx stuff... I probably goto his blog more than I goto the docs :P

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad you use it so much.

Comment: it had been working previously is the wierd thing. Love your blog! the docs are somewhat terible as they dont give good examples. unlike mike's blog hence where i got my script from i just took it a couple of step farther

Comment: i caught EVT_CLOSE and used onClose to hide it to the tray icon

Comment: If Phoenix ever gets finished, the documentation is supposed to get better as it will be easier to edit. Here's hoping that happens soon.

Comment: what exactly is pheniox